# Jsp with multiple form:input fields for phone number Spring MVC

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have 3 input boxes to enter a phone number. I am having trouble to get all the values and post submit the form.

```
<form:label path ="phonenumber">Phone number</form:label>
<form:input path="phonenumber" class="phonenumber" id="phonenumber1" maxlength="3"/>
<form:input path="phonenumber" class="phonenumber" id="phonenumber2" maxlength="3"/>
<form:input path="phonenumber" class="phonenumber" id="phonenumber3" maxlength="3"/>
```

When I submit the form only the first box value is passed.  How do I send the entire phone number?

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet you have tried so far

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the comment.

Comment: Is `path` equivalent to the input name? Or is ID mapped to the `name` property? Showing the rendered HTML would also be helpful.

Comment: path is equivalent to the Model Object property. id is just for the html.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

**form.jsp**

```
<input class="phonenumber" id="phonenumber1" maxlength="3"/>
<input class="phonenumber" id="phonenumber2" maxlength="3"/>
<input class="phonenumber" id="phonenumber3" maxlength="3"/>

<form:hidden path="phonenumber" class="phonenumber" id="phonenumber_insert"/>
```

And than use jQuery to get those values and insert to the hidden binded input

**script.js**

```
jQuery("#myForm").submit(function() {
    //first make some kind of validation for the three inputs
   var phonenumber1= jQuery("#phonenumber1").val();
   var phonenumber2= jQuery("#phonenumber2").val();
   var phonenumber3= jQuery("#phonenumber3").val();
//set to new field
jQuery("#phonenumber_insert").val(phonenumber1+phonenumber2+phonenumber3)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write different path for different phone number

eg. if you have 3 columns for phone number in db **(phonenumber1,phonenumber2,phonenumber3)** then you should write following code:

```
<form:label path ="phonenumber">Phone number</form:label>
<form:input path="phonenumber1" class="phonenumber" id="phonenumber1" 
maxlength="3"/>
<form:input path="phonenumber2" class="phonenumber" id="phonenumber2" 
 maxlength="3"/>
<form:input path="phonenumber3" class="phonenumber" id="phonenumber3"   
maxlength="3"/>
```

and submit with post